# "If" and "would be" when talking about future events

Tags: verbs, tenses

I am watching a basketball game right now, and the team that I am rooting for is losing. I want to say that if they win, that would be something. Which one is the correct way to state it?

> If Miami pulls this off, it would be something.
>   If Miami pulled this off, it would be something.
>   If Miami will pull this off, it will be something.

Hopefully, you get my drift.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
1. If Miami pulls this off, it would be something.
```

I would not say this, but some people would. The "pulls" is not counterfactual, but the "would" usually is.

```
2. If Miami pulled this off, it would be something.
```

This is normal for the counterfactual case.

```
3. If Miami will pull this off, it will be something.
```

This is not idiomatic in any variety of English, as far as I know. We don't use "will" in a conditional clause.

The usual form for 1 and 3  would be

```
4. If Miami pull this off, it will be something
```

So the canonical forms are 4 (present, future) and 2 (past, conditional). The difference in meaning is subtle, but exists: in 4  the event seems rather more likely than in 2 (which I have described as 'counterfactual').

Comment: +1 Nice summary. Technically 2 isn't necessarily counterfactual (because it *can* happen, it's just that the speaker thinks it's unlikely). A strict counterfactual would be "If Miami *had* pulled this off, it *would have been* something" (with an implicit "but they didn't").

Comment: @psmears: you're right, in the future everything is irrealis. But the distinctionin meaning is still there.

Comment: 4 is just wrong, Miami is singular here (one team), even though it has multiple members.

Comment: @Ben Voigt: but we can use the plural form all the same for teams, companies and other collectives; "Chelsea _are_ the champions", "Microsoft _are_ evil", and so on.

Comment: @Rhodri: There's an implied word in those sentences: "Chelsea players are the champions."  "Microsoft managers are evil."  That doesn't work in this scenario, because individual players don't "pull it off", the team does as a unit.

Comment: @Ben: I really don't buy that.  Do you have a reference to convince me with? :-)

Comment: @Rhodri: You haven't provided a reference for pairing a singular collection noun with a plural verb.  When you do, you'll find that it has such a restriction (it's only possible when the members of the collection are individually taking the action).  But [here](http://www.manhattangmat.com/forums/collective-nouns-singular-or-plural-t1398.html) is such reference.  And [another](http://www.chompchomp.com/terms/collectivenoun.htm) [more](http://uwf.edu/writelab/handouts/UsuageSummaryofRules/)

Comment: @Ben: I'll go look.  In the mean time, convince me that the members of the Miami collective _aren't_ individually taking action to pull it off in exactly the same sense that managers individually take action to be collectively evil.

Comment: @Rhodri: If the managers are collectively being evil, then the correct sentence is "Microsoft management *is* evil." and the plural must not be used.

Comment: @Ben: ironically, Colin's comment in [this answer](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2054/when-should-i-use-is-and-when-should-i-use-are/2080#2080) points out that this is a UK usage.  We should probably stop now.

Comment: @Rhodri: One, Miami isn't in the UK.  Two, Colin's comment that you linked reiterates the rule I've been trying to get across to you: A collective noun agrees with a plural verb only when the members are acting as individuals.

Comment: @Ben: One, Colin is in the UK.  Two, I concur with the links you provided, I just disagree with your interpretation of this instance.

Comment: As various people have said, "If Miami pull this off, it will be something" is perfectly grammatical, and indeed normal,  for me, because I speak BrE. I am aware that it is not grammatical for some. It was an error that I typed "pull" rather than "pulls", but only because of consistency with the earlier examples.

Comment: @Ben, as regards British English (which is what I speak and write) you are plain wrong, and your references are irrelevant. British English is comfortable with "The government is" and "the government are", and while there is sometimes a slight nuance of difference, it is not true that the use of the plural means that we are thinking of the members of the collective as individuals.

Comment: @Colin: I quote [your own comment](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2054/when-should-i-use-is-and-when-should-i-use-are/2080#2080): "it is well established in British usage that a collective noun (like 'team' or 'government', or even 'bank') can be construed with either a singular or a plural verb, depending on whether the collective is being considered as a unit or as a collection of individuals."

Comment: @Ben: Oops. I do seem to have reversed myself, don't I! But I stand by what I said above here: introspectively, when I say "the government are", or "ASDA are" I am thinking of a sort of amorphous mass, but not necessarily of individuals.

Comment: @Colin: I think I understand your point -- a government can be an entity, singular, or a group of individual persons, plural, or a group of subunits of various shapes and sizes, also plural.  The question then becomes, "Does Miami refer to a single team, or do a group of subsets (which may or may not be individual people)?"

Answer (score 6):

Here are a few examples.

A condition being possible in the present or the future:

> If he is late, we will have to go to the airport without him.
>
> If you heat water, it boils.
>
> If Miami pulls this off, it will make/makes it to the final. (*I believe that it is possible for Miami to pull it off.*)

A condition being unreal or improbable in the present or the future:

> If I were you, I would talk to my team.
>
> If I won the lottery, I would spend the entire money on a holiday.
>
> If Miami pulled this off, it would be something. (*Implies that it is quite improbable for Miami to pull this off.*)

A condition based on something that did not happen in the past:

> If she had stayed in the city, she would have found a new job.
>
> If he had known that the world would be destroyed, he never would have split the atom.
>
> If Miami had pulled this off, I would have been going to watch the final this year. (*This did not happen, but if it had, something else would have happened.*)

Comment: what about a condition being unreal or improbable in the **future** ?

Comment: @Anderson Silva: Good question. Edited the answer. We use the past tense with _would_ to denote improbability in the present or the future. (I am implying that my being you, my winning the lottery, and Miami pulling this off are all improbable or impossible.)

Comment: @Anderson Silva, @Tragicomic: There are lots of ways of indicating the future without using the verb tense, and in English, if you want to specifically indicate the future in conditionals, you have to use these. When you do that, you discover that the past tense doesn't work, at least not in my dialect. (Imagine substituting *pulled* for *were to pull* in the following sentence.) One correct way of doing this: *If Miami **were to pull** this off **in the next five minutes**, it would be something.*

Comment: @Peter Shor: While using the future subjunctive (as in your example) is correct, in hypothetical conditionals it is also correct to use the simple past to talk about unlikely and impossible situations. (Also see the example in @Colin Fine's example in his answer.) _If he went/were to go to the party, he would meet her_ as opposed to _if he goes to the party, he will meet her._

Comment: @Tragicomic: *"If Miami pulled this off in the next five minutes, it would be something."* really sounds wrong to me, while *"If he went to the party tomorrow, he would meet her."* sounds fine. I'm confused.

Comment: @Peter Shor: Perhaps it is because using the future subjunctive (_were to_) makes it sound more imaginary/impossible to you, which makes sense given the immediacy of all of this happening within _the next five minutes_. His going to the party, while unlikely, may sound more like a suggestion, and the past subjunctive (_went_) sounds alright. What you're saying makes sense. Both are grammatically correct, but it depends upon whether you want it to sound like a suggestion or wishful thinking.

Answer (score 0):

It should be the first example, and here's why:

As said by yourself, Miami is 'losing', which is in the present progressive form. Thus, the verb "pull" needs to be present as well.

Then, we have "would" instead of "will". The definition of "would" is as follows:

> Used as the auxiliary of the simple conditional mood (with a bare infinitive); *indicating an action or state that is conditional on another.* (Emphasis added)

It would be something, *only* if Miami pulls it off. So, we use *would* instead of *will*. I hope that explains it.

Comment: With would, we use the past subjunctive even when we are talking about the future, if we want it to sound unlikely or impossible.

Comment: @Tragicomic: That's the present subjunctive.  Past subjunctive: "If Miami had pulled it off, it *would have been* something."

Comment: @Ben Voigt: Present subjunctive: "It is important he _go_ to the party." "When Miami wins a game, I throw a party." Past subjunctive: "If Miami pulled this off, it would be something." Past perfect subjunctive or pluperfect subjunctive: "If Miami had pulled it off, it would have been something."

Comment: @Tragicomic: I guess you're right about the past perfect.  Only: "It is important *that* he go to the party."  Sounds really awkward otherwise.

Answer (score -1):

As others have noted, it depends on what outcome you think is probable.  But both clauses need to agree, and most of the other answers don't do this correctly.

If you expect Miami to win:

- *If Miami pulls this off, it will be something.*

Otherwise (subjunctive):

- *Were Miami to pull this off, it would be something.*