# Grammar behind the song title 'The Way I Are'

Tags: grammaticality, verbs, grammatical-number, verb-agreement

You might know the song called *The Way I Are* by Timberland featuring Keri Hilson. I am very confused here. How does *The Way I Are* make sense?

Comment: Expecting pop lyrics to make sense is... optimistic :-)

Comment: I'm not whoever voted to close this, but the sentence "All the things that my high-school teachers have taught were a lie" did tempt me to vote to close for peeving.  Perhaps explaining what confused you would make this question clearer for non-native English speakers reading it later on?

Comment: @Rhodri I think it explains the simplicity of the issue. If a person doesn't know that `am` should come after `I`, s/he shouldn't be here in the fist place. My comment is useless here because @Kosmonaut already took the sentence out from the question. This is the one thing I am not happy with stackexchange.

Comment: On the contrary, people who don't know about number agreement are exactly the people who ask [questions like this related one](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2054/when-should-i-use-is-and-when-should-i-use-are) on this site.  Your question could be more helpful to them.

Comment: @Rhodri I looked at the [link](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2054/when-should-i-use-is-and-when-should-i-use-are) you have provided and the question is not so basic. However, if a person has trouble on putting `am` after `I`, I don't think he can explain himself here.

Comment: The artiste's name is Timbaland (Timothy Zachery Mosley), by the way. Coincidentally, "_Timba_ is a Cuban genre of music based on popular Cuban music along with salsa, American funk/R&B, and the strong influence of Afro-Cuban folkloric music." See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timba.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about song lyrics

Comment: Of course, it makes sense. Aren't I?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not familiar with the song, but that title is **bad grammar**.

*I* is singular. *Are* would go with a plural subject. Perhaps the songwriter is hinting at having multiple personalities? Perhaps they wanted to do some other kind of word play or indicate that "they way he is" is broken, but there is no way to defend that title as grammatically correct!

The grammatically correct version would be "The way I am."

Comment: So, this is not something that we would like to use in our daily conversations?

Comment: @tugberk: Absolutely not!

Comment: But *you* is singular, and yet one uses *are* with *you*.

Comment: @nohat: That's sort of correct, except that you can be both singular or plural. I was giving the general rule not the exceptions. In this case the suggested phrase is not an exception and just plain wrong.

Comment: @Caleb my point is just that the verb *be* has the most complicated conjugation in English. By your logic, “the way I is” might be grammatical because *is* is for singular subjects and *I* is singular.

Comment: My explanation was purposed to show why it was wrong, not provide a formula for making it right. I'm not even sure I could give one :(

Answer (score 5):

Pop songs, and most forms of poetry, bend, break and totally ignore the rules of "proper grammar". See [poetic license](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artistic_license).

So yes, it doesn't match the rules, but that doesn't mean the rules are wrong --- just that they've been ignored.

Answer (score 4):

In the song's lyrics this mistake was made on purpose to rhyme it with another line.

> Baby if you strip, you could get a tip
>   'Cause I like you just the way you are
>   I'm about to strip and I want it quick
>   Can you handle me the way I are?

The title probably just inherited it from the lyrics. Also there's one more such mistake in the text, in the line *It don't matter 'cause I'm the one that loves you best*. It should be *it doesn't* — again, probably was made to fit the line into the song.

Comment: Reading the lines you have quoted, I think it is more than just rhyming: it is a deliberate catachresis to bring out the chiasmus: "I ... you the way you are" ... "You ... me the way I are".

Comment: And the "don't matter" is an _utterly_ different case. "the way I are" is not grammatical in the sense that it is something that no native English speaker (of any variety of English, AFAIK) would say. "It don't matter", on the other hand is something that many speakers of many varieties of English often say: it is not contrary to English grammar, just contrary to certain arbitrary varieties which have been deemed proper.

Comment: I agree with @ColinFine but the annoying thing is that the song would have worked with correct grammar!

Comment: Or to paraphrase your comment, @LesterCheung, the song would have worked if the writer had chosen not to write it in a version of English which they presumably found natural in the context, but in some other version of English which somebody has arbitrarily decided is "corrent gerammar". To which my answer is "Why on earth should they?"